# vmstat pidstat result analysis for Java program

Tags: java, linux, context-switch

**vmstat 1 100**

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----

r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st

1  0      0 2307452 283392 712136    0    0     2     2   17   21  0  1 99  0  0
 3  0      0 2307436 283392 712136    0    0     0     0 10677 3455 21 43 35  0  0
 4  0      0 2307436 283392 712136    0    0     0     0 10700 3620 22 42 36  0  0
 3  0      0 2307436 283392 712136    0    0     0     0 10549 3523 21 43 36  0  0

**pidstat -I -w -p 3809 2**

PID   cswch/s nvcswch/s  Command

3809      0.00      0.00  java

3809      0.00      0.00  java

3809      0.00      0.00  java

I am doing a pressure test. The server program is a WebSocket server, which accepts 10,000 client connections. Each client connection sends a message to server every 2 seconds, and server responds a message to each client every 2 seconds.

My question is :

1) From **vmstat 1 100**, it seems that the cpu( sy is 42%, us is 21% around) is doing much system-level work instead of user-level work. So I think there are too much context switch for CPU.

However, from **pidstat**, the **cswch/s** and **nvcswch/s** are all 0 for the server program.  I think this result means  that there are not much context switch for CPU.

Could anybody help explain the result of the Linux server monitoring result?

Answer (score 0):

- pidstat is referencing to process 3809
- vmstat is measuring all the processes of the system cause you set only the sampling frequency